# Gitlab import repos creates groups but no projects

Tags: git, gitlab, restore

After a gitlab upgrade, I have lost all configuration, and found that the backup I made was empty, so I could not restore a backup.

I've found that I still have the repos in `/home/git/repositories/` so I've copied them to `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories` and changed the user recursively to the gitlab user.

Now I have used the command `gitlab-rake gitlab:import:repos` and it has processed all repositories and has created the groups with an output like this:

`Processing fib/sdx.git
 * Created sdx (fib/sdx.git)
Processing fib/sdx.wiki.git
 * Skipping wiki repo`

The problem is that although it has created all groups and now I can see them in the gitlab web interface, it shows that each group has zero projects

[image]
¿How can I recover these repos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved at gitlab issue tracker.

The problem was that imported repos had a simlynk hooks that were pointing to an undefined folder.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2082